# Emulate three finger tap with the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, dictionary

I work with a MacBook and an external keyboard and would like to have the useful word lookup (three finger tap on the trackpad) by using a keyboard hotkey. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in shortcut which looks up the definition of the word on the cursor position: <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>